# Is the production of the T.V shows of Avatar going to stop being made?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

There has been some speculation from the producers and Viacom that after Book 3 Change and Book 4 of the TV show Legend of Korra, that they (Viacom and Nickelodeon) most likely will be finishing off Avatar afterwards and leave there.

I would like to know if this is:

1. Genuine.
2. I would like an answer based on some sort of fact, interview or video of some sort.
3. I do not want an opinion and want some sources on where you got your answer from, if possible.

Comment: I have improved my question to fit guidelines rather than a question based on opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm largely tempted to VTC as speculation since there all we really have is speculation at this point, but I *did* find a quote that provides a partial, as-of-right-now answer.

From [an interview with the creators](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2013/11/22/the-legend-of-korra-creators-writing-pretty-much-done-for-final-book-in-saga/) in November, 2013:

> *Where does the show go next beyond Book 2 and the in-the-works Book 3?*
>
> *Konietzko*: We’ve announced both Books 3 and 4.  And we’re pretty much done with writing on Book 4. So there’s a great deal of overlap in the production there. Book 4 is the end of the “Korra” series. So we’ve got 52 episodes planned. When all is said and done it will have taken I think about five years to make. Much like when “Avatar” ended, Mike and I need to just recharge the batteries and work on a couple of other things. **We definitely don’t have another series planned**, but I think this universe that we cracked open 11 years ago, I think it will always draw us back in, throughout the years, and I think it’s still an inspiring place for us to create and we have various other ideas, but we’re really busy just trying to get these episodes done and **we’re not actively trying to figure out the next step in this world yet.**

So, *as of right now*, any new material will be comics or other mediums, but no new television show or Avatar property is being planned.